Why solve SVD sign ambiguity (indeterminacy) problem choose inner product the singular vector and the individual data vectors?
onsider a matrix A = USV'
A = [1 2;3 4;5 6]
the matrix U is
[-0.23 0.97;-0.97 -0.23;0.06 -0.01]
choose the first column of A as the individual data vector a1 = (1,3,5)
the inner product of u1 is
u1 * a1=-0.23 * 1+-0.97 * 3+0.06 * 5=-3.11
so the inner product is negative, choose flip the sign of u1 = -u1 = (0.23, 0.97,-0.06)
So Why does multiplying a column of data give direction of singular vector? What is the meaning of this process? Mentioned in "Resolving the Sign Ambiguity in the
Singular Value Decomposition" by R. Bra, E. Acar, T. Kolda in 2008.
paper image
I was try to using PCA on my image, find out why the direction is always choose the thin end

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.
